# Fetch hourly data from MySQL

Tags: mysql

The query below retrieves Date Hourly and groups the data into hourly format

```
SELECT Hour(created)   AS hour, created,image
    FROM   user_screenshot
    WHERE  created BETWEEN ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - 
                              INTERVAL 23 hour ) AND Now() AND date(created) = '2021-01-27'
    GROUP  BY hour 
    ORDER  BY ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour )
```

It prints the data this way [image]

which is okay. But Is it possible to retrieve all the records as well which belongs to that hour. For the example above query says there are `447` records in hour `21` and `1` result in `22` hour. Is it possible in one query to fetch those results as well which exist in the database against those hours.

Expecting Output this way

[image]

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: yes, with join of the same table. try that

Comment: @fadlikidd can you please edit my query?

Comment: I can but how do you plan to show all the records? by row? Also your final result output, do you require the `hour` and `count` information? These information I/we need to know before we can suggest anything. If not, we'll end up with a very long and unnecessary comments. The link @Strawberry posted can guide you through. As for now I can suggest you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65933673/edit) and post an illustration of your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @fadlikidd I'll update my question. I do not need count though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this Using INNER JOIN on the same table.

```
SELECT a.hour, a.Count, b.* FROM user_screenshot as b 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Hour(created) AS hour, created, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM   user_screenshot  
WHERE  created BETWEEN ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour ) AND Now()
GROUP BY hour
ORDER  BY ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour )
) as a 
ON Hour(a.created) = Hour(b.created) WHERE date(b.created) = '2021-01-27'
```

Comment: @hitesh, Thank you very much. Is it possible to start the hour in ascending order instead of descending order?

Comment: please check my expected output if it can be possible?

Comment: Yes, you can by adding this in query "ORDER BY a.hour DESC". Hope helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Group_concat()` function to get all those values as an single array.

Example.

```
Group_concat(column_name) as alias_name,
```

this will get all the values in a single row